# Is javax.resource.ResourceException an instance of javax.persistence.PersistenceException?

Tags: exception

I want to know how is "javax.resource.ResourceException" related to "javax.persistence.PersistenceException"

Comment: I am trying to construct a exception message based on the exception.

Comment: if (exception instanceof ResourceException){                                                                      message.append("could not connect to ").append(dbName).append("at the moment");}....................but im not able to catch it as an instance of persistenceException